# Can I remove record set TXT for Office 365 on Route 53

Tags: outlook, office365, amazon-route53

I have a record set TXT in Route 53, cause I need create a TXT record verification for Google Search, can I delete this? Is this also for some verification purpose? Should it be there forever?

[image]

Comment: I hope you're asking about this `MS=ms8888888`, not SPF. Anyway, I think it should belong to [sf], not [SO] :)

Comment: @robdy thw whole reccord set. sorry for privacy, changed the actual number to 8888888

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [Create DNS records at any DNS hosting provider for Office 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/get-help-with-domains/create-dns-records-at-any-dns-hosting-provider?view=o365-worldwide):

> NOTE: This record is used only to verify that you own your domain; it doesn't affect anything else. **You can delete it later, if you like.**

It refers to `MS=msxxxxxx` record, so you can delete it safely.

When it comes to SPF, I'd not touch it as it's responsible for specifying who's allowed to send email from your domain. If you delete it you basically don't specify the list of allowed servers which is **really not recommended**.

However, the information under the text box says that you can enter multiple values on separate lines so you can just add another line for Google verification.

Comment: the support of multi-lines sounds interesting and safe to me.

Comment: Yup, it's not very good when you can set only one TXT record, especially if the newer one overrides the old one. Happened to me once...